# How to put the retrieved database value inside the javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am retrieved value from the database,i want to put my retrieved data in the JavaScript,i am storing my retrieved value like this `$data1 =25` , in my JavaScript code instead of  `data: 50` i want  to put the retrieved $data1 =25,can anyone guide to do it ,thanks.

my java script code

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($.fn.plot) {

var dataPie = [{
                label: "Samsung",
                data: 50
            }

}
});

});
```

Comment: first you use jquery or ajax to send data to php, do you php stuff, than echo the result and in jquery you can collect data like `.done(function(response){ alert(response);});`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some like that:

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($.fn.plot) {
            var dataPie = [{
                label: "Samsung",
                data: <?php echo $data1 ?>
            }];
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This requires that the Javascript is inlined, which is bad practice. Don't build Javascript dyncamically. Just query a PHP script from Javascript that returns, for example, JSON.

Comment: @IngoBürk, I know it, thank you.

Comment: @Sergey i tried its not working

Comment: Downvote: without explanation this answer is useless. Will only work in specific circumstances (JS is generated by a PHP file).

Comment: @Xavi, you have to learn about pass data from PHP to Javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript , it's not simple like i wrote